# Get one line of user input and then execute it as Bash commands

Tags: linux, bash, expect

I have wrote a expect script that helps to execute commands in remote machine. When the execution is completed, I want to get one line of user input and then send it to the remote bash, here is the code snippet:

```
#! /usr/bin/env expect
...
spawn ssh -l $user $host
...
send_tty -- "Enter your command: " 
set timeout -1

# match only printable characters (prevent from pressing TAB)
expect_tty eof exit -re {([[:print:]]*)\n}
send_tty -- "\n"
set timeout 10

# send the command to remote shell
send "$expect_out(1,string)" 
expect "$GENERAL_PROMPT"
```

However, if the input is something like: `ls /"`, my program will be blocked because the remote shell expects to get more characters by prompting the string "> ". Actually, I hope bash won't prompt for more input instead of just printing error message:

```
$ read COMMAND
ls /"
$ eval "$COMMAND"
bash: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
bash: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Can I achieve this in my script?

Comment: @ zhujs : I'm no bash expert, but, when I simply tried executing the `read COMMAND` with `ls /"` as input  and  `eval $COMMAND` and I got the above error in the terminal. If the input does not have not double quotes, i.e. `ls /`, then it is working fine.

Comment: I just want my script to print the same error when user input `ls /"`

Comment: Use `eval` just like you tried.

Comment: Use multiPrompt. `set multiPrompt {[>\"] }`

Comment: @whjm I have tried this command: `send "eval $expect_out(1,string)"`, but my program still got blocked

Comment: @MaheshKharvi , what I want is to force bash to spit out the error message, not prompt for more input

Comment: Are you running it loop?

Comment: @MaheshKharvi Yes, I can get what I want using the bash `read` command just like in the above example

Comment: @zhujs, what happens if user enters correct command. I feel that is missing in your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set prompt "#|%|>|\\\$ $"; # A generalized prompt to match known prompts.
spawn ssh -l dinesh xxx.xx.xx.xxx
expect {
    "(yes/no)" { send "yes\r";exp_continue}
    "password" 
}
send "mypassword\r"
expect -re $prompt
send_tty -- "Enter your command: " 
set timeout -1

# match only printable characters (prevent from pressing TAB)
expect_tty eof exit -re {([[:print:]]*)\n}
send_tty -- "\n"
set timeout 10
puts "\nUSER INPUT : $expect_out(1,string)"

# send the command to remote shell 
# Using 'here-doc', to handle possible user inputs, instead of quoting it with any other symbol like single quotes or backticks
send "read COMMAND <<END\r"
expect -re $prompt
send "$expect_out(1,string)\r" 
expect -re $prompt
send "END\r"
expect -re $prompt

# Since we want to send the literal dollar sign, I am sending it within braces
send {eval $COMMAND}
# Now sending 'Return' key
send "\r"
expect -re $prompt
```

**Why 'here-doc' used ?**

If I have used backticks or single quotes to escape the commands, then if user gave backticks or single quotes in the commands itself, then it may fail. So, to overcome that only, I have added here-doc.

**Output :**

```
dinesh@MyPC:~/stackoverflow$ ./zhujs
spawn ssh -l dinesh xxx.xx.xx.xxx
dinesh@xxx.xx.xx.xxx's password: 

[dinesh@lab ~]$ matched_literal_dollar_sign
Enter your command: ls /"


USER INPUT : ls /"
read COMMAND <<END
> ls /"
> END
[dinesh@lab ~]$ eval $COMMAND
-bash: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
-bash: syntax error: unexpected end of file
[dinesh@lab ~]$ dinesh@MyPC:~/stackoverflow$
```

**Update :**

The main reason for using `here-doc` is due to the fact that it makes the read to act as non-blocking command. i.e. We can proceed quickly with next command. Else, we have to wait till the timeout of `Expect`. (Of course, we could change the timeout value dynamically.)

This is just one way of doing it. You can alter it if you want, with simply having the `read` command.

Comment: Wow, it seems that will work, can you explain your `Why 'here-doc' used` with an example?

Comment: Updated the output. Hope that helps.

Comment: "If I have used backticks or single quotes to escape the commands, then if user gave backticks or single quotes in the commands itself, then it may fail." what does this means?

Comment: @zhujs : Without `here-doc`, the commands can be evaluated as `eval '<cmd>'`. If user gives command as `ls /"`, it will throw the expected error message.  But, if suppose, user gives single quotes in the commands itself, i.e. `ls '`, then during evaluation it will become `eval 'ls ''` which makes it wait for the rest of the commands.  Same thing is applicable for backticks as well. (I can't give backticks example here, as stackoverflow uses backticks for the `code` formatted text ;-) ) Hope you got this.

Comment: Without `here-doc`, expect will get blocked, because the `read` command will ask for more input, not bash. However the `her-doc` version works for me, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think this would be a good case for `interact` -- get expect to step aside and let the user interact directly with the spawned program.

```
spawn ssh -l $user $host
#...

send_user "You are now about to take control: type QQQ to return control to the program\n"

interact {
    QQQ   return
}

send_user "Thanks, I'm back in charge ...\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a one line version

`read > export cmd ; eval $cmd ; unset cmd`